# Installing mysql.data.mysqlclient using mysql connector but no bin folder?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, odbc

I would like to connect to our remote mysql db using VB.NET but I'm having issues with installing a .dll file. I need to add mysql.data.mysqlclient reference but can't find bin folder containing .dll file. I did many google and stack overflow searches but haven't stumbled on any solutions.

1. I downloaded [mysql connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html%20to%20my%20desktop)
2. Unzipped it
3. Opened Visual Studio 2010 Express and created new project
4. Under solutions explorer, right clicked to add reference
5. Then browsed to unzipped mysql connector folder to find bin folder

This bin folder isn't anywhere to be found. I'm missing something, any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1102310/284240

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a reference to the MySQL connector for .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102281/how-do-i-add-a-reference-to-the-mysql-connector-for-net)

Comment: @TimSchmelter No it's not. As I've stated above I've already downloaded mysql connector and there is no bin folder. Please take another look.

Comment: Make sure you downloaded the second one (mysql-connector-net-6.0.7.zip) which is the one that contains the installer.
The first one (mysql-connector-net-6.0.7-src.zip) is the source code.

Comment: @xfx that did the trick, i didn't install the connector so there was no bin. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install the mysql connector to your machine. Then open your project, right click, and click 'add reference', find 'mysql.data' at the '.NET' tab.