# Adding Database query to existing project

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-2013

I was wondering if you could help me out. Ive been stuck on this for a long time. I have google searched just about everything i possibly can but no luck!
I am currently working with the Jarvis project files. It is a voice command program. I would like for Jarvis to Query a Mysql databse and if the value of something is one then i would like it say "its on" or whatever. Thats not what im stuck on. What im stuck on is adding the CORRECT querying code into this existing project. Here is the code that needs the query.

I am using the Mysql.Data.MySqlClient. I have no idea how to retrieve these valuables from my database. Any guidance would be amazing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using CustomizeableJarvis.Properties;
using System.Globalization;

namespace CustomizeableJarvis
{
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    public static List<string> MsgList = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> MsgLink = new List<string>();
    int count = 1;
    int timer = 11;
    int EmailNum = 0;
    DateTime timenow = DateTime.Now;
    public static String Temperature, Condition, Humidity, WinSpeed, TFCond, TFHigh, TFLow, Town;

    void Default_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        int ranNum;
        string speech = e.Result.Text;
        switch (speech)
        {
            #region Greetings
            case "Hello":
            case "Hello Jarvis":
                timenow = DateTime.Now;
                if (timenow.Hour >= 5 && timenow.Hour < 12)
                { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Goodmorning " + Settings.Default.User); }
                if (timenow.Hour >= 12 && timenow.Hour < 18)
                { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Good afternoon " + Settings.Default.User); }
                if (timenow.Hour >= 18 && timenow.Hour < 24)
                { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Good evening " + Settings.Default.User); }
                if (timenow.Hour < 5)
                { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Hello " + Settings.Default.User + ", it's getting late"); }
                break;

            case "Goodbye":
            case "Goodbye Jarvis":
            case "Close Jarvis":
                Jarvis.Speak("Farewell");
                Close();
                break;

            case "Jarvis":
                ranNum = rnd.Next(1, 5);
                if (ranNum == 1) { QEvent = ""; Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Yes sir"); }
                else if (ranNum == 2) { QEvent = ""; Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Yes?"); }
                else if (ranNum == 3) { QEvent = ""; Jarvis.SpeakAsync("How may I help?"); }
                else if (ranNum == 4) { QEvent = ""; Jarvis.SpeakAsync("How may I be of assistance?"); }
                break;

            case "What's my name?":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync(Settings.Default.User);
                break;

            case "Stop talking":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
                ranNum = rnd.Next(1, 5);
                if (ranNum == 5)
                { Jarvis.Speak("fine"); }
                break;
            #endregion

            #region Condition of the Day
            case "What time is it":
                timenow = DateTime.Now;
                string time = timenow.GetDateTimeFormats('t')[0];
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync(time);
                break;

            case "What day is it":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync(DateTime.Today.ToString("dddd"));
                break;

            case "Whats the date":
            case "Whats todays date":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
                break;

            case "Hows the weather":
            case "Whats the weather like":
            case "Whats it like outside":
                RSSReader.GetWeather();
                if (QEvent == "connected")
                { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("The weather in " + Town + " is " + Condition + " at " + Temperature + " degrees. There is a humidity of " + Humidity + " and a windspeed of " + WinSpeed + " miles per hour"); }
                else if (QEvent == "failed")
                { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("I seem to be having a bit of trouble connecting to the server. Just look out the window"); }
                break;

            case "What will tomorrow be like":
            case "Whats tomorrows forecast":
            case "Whats tomorrow like":
                RSSReader.GetWeather();
                if (QEvent == "connected")
                { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Tomorrows forecast is " + TFCond + " with a high of " + TFHigh + " and a low of " + TFLow); }
                else if (QEvent == "failed")
                { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("I could not access the server, are you sure you have the right W O E I D?"); }
                break;

            case "Whats the temperature":
            case "Whats the temperature outside":
                RSSReader.GetWeather();
                if (QEvent == "connected")
                { Jarvis.SpeakAsync(Temperature + " degrees"); }
                else if (QEvent == "failed")
                { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("I could not connect to the weather service"); }
                break;
            #endregion

            #region Application Commands
            case "Switch Window":
                SendKeys.SendWait("%{TAB " + count + "}");
                count += 1;
                break;

            case "Close window":
                SendKeys.SendWait("%{F4}");
                break;

            case "Out of the way":
                if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
                {
                    WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync("My apologies");
                }
                break;

            case "Come back":
                if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                {
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Alright");
                    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                }
                break;

            case "Are Lights on?":
                JARVIS_SpeakCompleted.SpeakAsync("Let Me Check");
                break;

            case "Show default commands":
                string[] defaultcommands = (File.ReadAllLines(@"Default Commands.txt"));
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Very well");
                lstCommands.Items.Clear();
                lstCommands.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
                lstCommands.Visible = true;
                foreach (string command in defaultcommands)
                {
                    lstCommands.Items.Add(command);
                }
                break;

            case "Show shell commands":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Here we are");
                lstCommands.Items.Clear();
                lstCommands.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
                lstCommands.Visible = true;
                foreach (string command in ArrayShellCommands)
                {
                    lstCommands.Items.Add(command);
                }
                break;

            case "Show social commands":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Alright");
                lstCommands.Items.Clear();
                lstCommands.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
                lstCommands.Visible = true;
                foreach (string command in ArraySocialCommands)
                {
                    lstCommands.Items.Add(command);
                }
                break;

            case "Show web commands":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Ok");
                lstCommands.Items.Clear();
                lstCommands.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
                lstCommands.Visible = true;
                foreach (string command in ArrayWebCommands)
                {
                    lstCommands.Items.Add(command);
                }
                break;
            case "Show Music Library":
                lstCommands.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
                lstCommands.Items.Clear();
                lstCommands.Visible = true;
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("OK");
                i = 0;
                foreach (string file in MyMusicPaths)
                {
                    lstCommands.Items.Add(MyMusicNames[i]);
                    i += 1;
                }
                QEvent = "Play music file";
                break;

            case "Show Video Library":
                lstCommands.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
                lstCommands.Items.Clear();
                lstCommands.Visible = true;
                i = 0;
                foreach (string file in MyVideoPaths)
                {
                    if (file.Contains(".mp4") || file.Contains(".avi") || file.Contains(".mkv"))
                    { lstCommands.Items.Add(MyVideoNames[i]); i += 1; }
                    else { i += 1; }
                }
                QEvent = "Play video file";
                break;

            case "Show Email List":
                lstCommands.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
                lstCommands.Items.Clear();
                lstCommands.Visible = true;
                foreach (string line in MsgList)
                {
                    lstCommands.Items.Add(line);
                }
                QEvent = "Checkfornewemails";
                break;

            case "Show listbox":
                lstCommands.Visible = true;
                break;

            case "Hide listbox":
                lstCommands.Visible = false;
                break;
            #endregion

            #region Shutdown / Restart / Logoff
            case "Shutdown":
                if (ShutdownTimer.Enabled == false)
                {
                    QEvent = "shutdown";
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Are you sure you want to " + QEvent + "?");
                }
                break;

            case "Log off":
                if (ShutdownTimer.Enabled == false)
                {
                    QEvent = "logoff";
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Are you sure you want to " + QEvent + "?");
                }
                break;

            case "Restart":
                if (ShutdownTimer.Enabled == false)
                {
                    QEvent = "restart";
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Are you sure you want to " + QEvent + "?");
                }
                break;

            case "Abort":
                if (ShutdownTimer.Enabled == true)
                {
                    timer = 11;
                    lblTimer.Text = timer.ToString();
                    ShutdownTimer.Enabled = false;
                    lblTimer.Visible = false;
                }
                break;
            #endregion

            #region Media Control Commands
            case "Play":
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Visible = true;
                break;
            case "Play a random song":
                int Ran = rnd.Next(0, MyMusicPaths.Count());
                SelectedMusicFile = Ran;
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("I hope you're in the mood for " + MyMusicNames[SelectedMusicFile]);
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = MyMusicPaths[SelectedMusicFile];
                break;
            case "You decide":
                if (QEvent == "Play music")
                {
                    Ran = rnd.Next(0, MyMusicPaths.Count());
                    SelectedMusicFile = Ran;
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync("How about " + MyMusicNames[SelectedMusicFile] + "?");
                    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = MyMusicPaths[SelectedMusicFile];
                }
                break;
            case "Pause":
                tmrMusic.Stop();
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause();
                break;
            case "Turn Shuffle On":
                Settings.Default.Shuffle = true;
                Settings.Default.Save();
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Shuffle enabled");
                break;
            case "Turn Shuffle Off":
                Settings.Default.Shuffle = false;
                Settings.Default.Save();
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Shuffle disabled");
                break;
            case "Turn Up":
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume += 10;
                lblVolume.Text = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume.ToString() + "%";
                tbarVolume.Value = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume;
                break;
            case "Turn Down":
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume -= 10;
                lblVolume.Text = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume.ToString() + "%";
                tbarVolume.Value = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume;
                break;
            case "Mute":
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.mute = true;
                lblVolume.Text = "mute";
                break;
            case "Unmute":
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.mute = false;
                lblVolume.Text = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume.ToString() + "%";
                break;
            case "Next Song":
                if (SelectedMusicFile != MyMusicPaths.Count() - 1)
                {
                    if (Settings.Default.Shuffle == true)
                    {
                        Ran = rnd.Next(0, MyMusicPaths.Count());
                        SelectedMusicFile = Ran;
                    }
                    else if (Settings.Default.Shuffle == false)
                    { SelectedMusicFile += 1; }
                    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = MyMusicPaths[SelectedMusicFile];
                }
                break;
            case "Previous Song":
                if (SelectedMusicFile != 0)
                {
                    SelectedMusicFile -= 1;
                    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = MyMusicPaths[SelectedMusicFile];
                }
                break;
            case "Fast Forward":
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.fastForward();
                break;
            case "Stop Music":
                tmrMusic.Stop();
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = String.Empty;
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
                lblMusicTime.Visible = false; 
                lblVolume.Visible = false;
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Visible = false;
                tbarVolume.Visible = false; 
                tbarMusicTime.Visible = false;
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = false;
                break;
            case "Fullscreen":
                try
                {
                    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = true;
                }
                catch { }
                break;
            case "Exit Fullscreen":
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = false;
                break;
            case "What song is playing":
                string filesourceURL = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.sourceURL;
                if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
                { Jarvis.SpeakAsync(MyMusicNames[SelectedMusicFile]); }
                else
                { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("No song is currently being played"); }
                break;
            #endregion

            #region Other Commands
            case "I want to add custom commands":
            case "I want to add a custom command":
            case "I want to add a command":
                Customize customwindow = new Customize();
                customwindow.ShowDialog();
                break;

            case "Update commands":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("This may take a few seconds");
                _recognizer.UnloadGrammar(shellcommandgrammar);
                _recognizer.UnloadGrammar(webcommandgrammar);
                _recognizer.UnloadGrammar(socialcommandgrammar);
                ArrayShellCommands = File.ReadAllLines(scpath);
                ArrayShellResponse = File.ReadAllLines(srpath);
                ArrayShellLocation = File.ReadAllLines(slpath);
                ArrayWebCommands = File.ReadAllLines(webcpath);
                ArrayWebResponse = File.ReadAllLines(webrpath);
                ArrayWebURL = File.ReadAllLines(weblpath);
                ArraySocialCommands = File.ReadAllLines(socpath);
                ArraySocialResponse = File.ReadAllLines(sorpath);
                try
                { shellcommandgrammar = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(ArrayShellCommands))); _recognizer.LoadGrammar(shellcommandgrammar); }
                catch
                { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("I've detected an in valid entry in your shell commands, possibly a blank line. Shell commands will cease to work until it is fixed."); }
                try
                { webcommandgrammar = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(ArrayWebCommands))); _recognizer.LoadGrammar(webcommandgrammar); }
                catch
                { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("I've detected an in valid entry in your web commands, possibly a blank line. Web commands will cease to work until it is fixed."); }
                try
                { socialcommandgrammar = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(ArraySocialCommands))); _recognizer.LoadGrammar(socialcommandgrammar); }
                catch
                { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("I've detected an in valid entry in your social commands, possibly a blank line. Social commands will cease to work until it is fixed."); }
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("All commands updated");
                break;

            case "Refresh libraries":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Loading libraries");
                try { _recognizer.UnloadGrammar(MusicGrammar); _recognizer.UnloadGrammar(VideoGrammar); }
                catch { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Previous grammar was invalid"); }
                File.Delete(@"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\\Documents\\Jarvis Custom Commands\\Filenames.txt");
                QEvent = "ReadDirectories";
                ReadDirectories();
                break;
            case "Change video directory":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Please choose a directory to load your video files");
                VideoFBD.SelectedPath = Settings.Default.VideoFolder;
                VideoFBD.Description = "Please select your video directory";
                DialogResult videoresult = VideoFBD.ShowDialog();
                if (videoresult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Settings.Default.VideoFolder = VideoFBD.SelectedPath; Settings.Default.Save();
                    QEvent = "ReadDirectories";
                    ReadDirectories();
                }
                break;
            case "Change music directory":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Please choose a directory to load your music files");
                MusicFBD.SelectedPath = Settings.Default.MusicFolder;
                MusicFBD.Description = "Please select your music directory";
                DialogResult musicresult = MusicFBD.ShowDialog();
                if (musicresult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Settings.Default.MusicFolder = MusicFBD.SelectedPath; Settings.Default.Save();
                    QEvent = "ReadDirectories";
                    ReadDirectories();
                }
                break;

            case "Stop listening":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("I will await further commands");
                _recognizer.RecognizeAsyncCancel();
                startlistening.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
                break;
            #endregion

            #region Gmail Notification
            case "Check for new emails":
                QEvent = "Checkfornewemails";
                Jarvis.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
                EmailNum = 0;
                RSSReader.CheckForEmails();
                break;
            case "Open the email":
                try
                {
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Very well");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(MsgLink[EmailNum]);
                }
                catch { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("There are no emails to read"); }
                break;
            case "Read the email":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
                try
                {
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync(MsgList[EmailNum]);
                }
                catch { Jarvis.SpeakAsync("There are no emails to read"); }
                break;
            case "Next email":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
                try
                {
                    EmailNum += 1;
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync(MsgList[EmailNum]);
                }
                catch { EmailNum -= 1; Jarvis.SpeakAsync("There are no further emails"); }
                break;
            case "Previous email":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
                try
                {
                    EmailNum -= 1;
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync(MsgList[EmailNum]);
                }
                catch { EmailNum += 1; Jarvis.SpeakAsync("There are no previous emails"); }
                break;
            case "Clear email list":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
                MsgList.Clear(); MsgLink.Clear(); lstCommands.Items.Clear(); EmailNum = 0; Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Email list has been cleared");
                break;
            #endregion

            #region Updating
            case "Change Language":
                AskForACountry();
                break;
            case "Check for new updates":
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Let me see if Michael has posted anything");
                RSSReader.CheckBloggerForUpdates();
                break;
            case "Yes":
                if (QEvent == "UpdateYesNo")
                {
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Thank you. I shall initialize the download immediately. Simply uninstall me and then install the new me. Would you like me to open the blog for specific information on the update?");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Settings.Default.RecentUpdate);
                    QEvent = "OpenBlog";
                }
                else if (QEvent == "OpenBlog")
                {
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Very well, consider it done");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://michaelcjarvis.blogspot.com/2013/09/michael-cs-customizable-jarvis.html");
                    QEvent = String.Empty;
                }
                else if (QEvent == "shutdown" || QEvent == "logoff" || QEvent == "restart")
                {
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync("I will begin the countdown to " + QEvent);
                    ShutdownTimer.Enabled = true;
                    lblTimer.Visible = true;
                }
                break;
            case "No":
                if (QEvent == "UpdateYesNo")
                {
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Very well. I guess I don't need any improvement");
                    Settings.Default.RecentUpdate = String.Empty; Settings.Default.Save();
                    QEvent = String.Empty;
                }
                else if (QEvent == "OpenBlog")
                {
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Learn by doing I suppose");
                    QEvent = String.Empty;
                }
                else if (QEvent == "shutdown" || QEvent == "logoff" || QEvent == "restart")
                {
                    Jarvis.SpeakAsync("My mistake");
                    QEvent = String.Empty;
                }
                break;
            #endregion
        }
    }
    void startlistening_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        string speech = e.Result.Text;
        switch (speech)
        {
            case "Jarvis":
                startlistening.RecognizeAsyncCancel();
                Jarvis.SpeakAsync("Yes?");
                _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is where i need the code

```
case "Are Lights on?":
  JARVIS_SpeakCompleted.SpeakAsync("Let Me Check");
  break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't saw any usage of Mysql here. For starting, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102281/how-do-i-add-a-reference-to-the-mysql-connector-for-net) How to add a reference to the MySQL connector for .NET and [here](http://bitdaddys.com/MySQL-ConnectorNet.html) how to connect to Mysql and receive some data.