# DLL Hell - My application throws an error if Version 6.9.3.0 OR 6.8.3.0 of MySql.Data.dll is missing

Tags: c#, mysql

**Problem Context**

I have written an application in C# which uses a MySqlConnector. I've added `MySql.Data.dll` (Version 6.9.3.0) to the `References` - this all works as expected on my PC (running Windows 7). However, starting with recent builds, when I try to run the application on another PC (running Windows XP), it throws an Exception on startup.

I added an `UnhandledExceptionEventHandler` which shows the error `Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version 6.8.3.0. (...etc...)' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest description does not match the assembly reference. File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, (...etc...)`.

Obviously it is looking for Version 6.8.3.0 but only finding Version 6.9.3.0 in the References - but what I want to know is *why* it is looking for this version when it worked correctly with earlier builds, and *how* I can specify which version of MySql to look for.

I know I could just add another reference to the earlier version of the `.dll`, but I want to understand why this is happening.

**Steps taken to attempt to diagnose the problem**

- Checked the project's `References` after seeing [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102281/how-do-i-add-a-reference-to-the-mysql-connector-for-net) and confirming that a reference to `MySql.Data.dll` has been added to the project, along with its version (`6.9.3.0`).
- Searched for results relating to the Exception error message and found [this article on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference) describing its cause (which I was aware of, but it confirms it)
- A colleague asked me to confirm that the `SpecificVersion` property of the `MySql.Data` Reference is set to `False` (it is).
- Tried adding an assembly binding to the config as suggested in an answer below - it does not help, the same error is thrown.
- Replaced the `MySqlData.dll` on the other PC with version `6.8.3.0` as a 'dirty fix' to see what happened. It now throws the same error as before, but for missing `6.9.3.0`.
- Asked a colleague to run the application on his (Windows 7) PC - no error was generated and it worked as expected.
- I tried using the `Dependency Walker` utility on the `.exe` as a commenter suggested but it only showed the following .dlls missing - `IESHIMS.DLL` (on both PCs), `WER.DLL` (on the XP PC), and `GPSVC.DLL` (on my PC). There was nothing about `MySql.Data.dll`. (Though I have since learned this is *not* a useful tool in this case - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227886/how-do-i-determine-the-dependencies-of-a-net-application).)
- On a whim, I decided to change the `SpecificVersion` property of `MySql.Data` Reference to `True` - this fixes the problem.

---

**Additional Information**

My `app.config` file -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/> 
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you shows your config file?

Comment: I have added it above.

Comment: you could use DependencyWalker to see if there is another dependency on MySQLData.dll that you didn't spot yet.

Comment: Dependency walker is not a good choice here, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227886/how-do-i-determine-the-dependencies-of-a-net-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the `SpecificVersion`property of the `MySql.Data` Reference to `True` fixed the problem.

My hypothesis is that the application was *somehow* simultaneously looking for versions `6.8.3.0.` and `6.9.3.0.` simultaneously - however by specifying a specific version it doesn't "confuse itself" and just goes for `6.9.3.0.`, which is there.

Comment: Did you try using ILDASM and check the dependents DLL versions in the related DLLs. This one and binding redirections / .net framework version in the project worked earlier for me