# Database connection doesn't work C#

Tags: c#, database, connection, database-connection

I'm working on a program in C#. I created a database with MySQL on phpMyAdmin and I want to connect this database with my program.
After the connection I have to insert, update, delete and view all the data, but I have a problem: the connection doesn't work.

I post here my code for the connection:

```
public static string StringaConnessione = "Data Source=localhost;Database=agility;userid=root;password='';";
public static MySqlConnection Connessione = new MySqlConnection(StringaConnessione);
```

When I write the code for the insert button I have another problem (is certainly for the database)

```
Connessione.Open();
SQLDataAdapter SDA=new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO GARA(nome_gara,giudice,località,data,tpsopm,tpmopm,tpstot,tpmtot)VALUES('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"','"+textBox5.Text+"','"+textBox6.Text+"','"+textBox7.Text+"','"+textBox8.Text+"')",Connessione);
SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
Connessione.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Dati salvati correttamente!");
```

May you help me, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a `SqlDataAdapter` to talk to `MySQL` as that class is designed for use with Sql Server.

Use the [`MySqlDataAdapter`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataAdapter.htm) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have so many problems with your code:

1) You are using static connection, there is Connection pool and it is your friend.

2) You are not using your connection in using block or in try/catch/finally/block 
to ensure closing of connection on exception.

3) **Blocker problem**: You are using SqlDataAdapter instead of MySqlDataAdapter

4) **Blocker problem** You should define your Insert query in `InsertCommand` of the `DataAdapter`, it will not work with `SelectCommand`. Even better just use `MySqlCommand` and `ExecuteNonQuery` on it.

5) You are not protected from Sql Injection(Use MySqlCommand.Parameters)

6) Bad formatting of your variables, textboxes and db fields.

How your code will look optimally:

```
public static string connetionString= "Data Source=localhost;Database=agility;userid=root;password='';";

public void SomeMethod()
{

    using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connetionString));
    {
         conn.Open();

         string query = @"INSERT INTO GARA
                             (nome_gara, giudice, località, data, tpsopm, tpmopm, tpstot, tpmtot)
                          VALUES
                             (@Param1, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4, @Param5, @Param6, @Param7, @Param8)";

         MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"query", conn);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", textBox1.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", textBox2.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param3", textBox3.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param4", textBox4.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param5", textBox5.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param6", textBox6.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param7", textBox7.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param8", textBox8.Text);

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should discard all your code.
and find a valid one to start

for example this
http://roboardgod.blogspot.hk/2013/08/cmysql.html

you may need to add the reference MySql.Data.MySqlClient manually. check this post to add the reference
[How do I add a reference to the MySQL connector for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102281/how-do-i-add-a-reference-to-the-mysql-connector-for-net)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace MySQLtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   string dbHost = "";//db address, for example localhost
            string dbUser = "";//dbusername
            string dbPass = "";//dbpassword
            string dbName = "";//db name
            string connStr = "server=" + dbHost + ";uid=" + dbUser + ";pwd=" + dbPass + ";database=" + dbName;
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            conn.Open();

            String cmdText = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE level < 50";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //execure the reader
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    String s = reader.GetString(i);
                    Console.Write(s + "\t");
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```