# MySql reference

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

Ive followed this guide to install the reference. [How do I add a reference to the MySQL connector for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102281/how-do-i-add-a-reference-to-the-mysql-connector-for-net).
When the reference is added, all errors go away, but when I try to run it, I get this error:
"The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)"

As you can see from the screencap, the reference shows up under 'references'.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok Sorted it, If you use framwork 4, like me, you need to use the reference version 6.3.5.0
Thanks