# Is it possible to use the MySQL .NET connector for a c# project without using NuGet in VS Code

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am building a .net webapi backend for a project I'm working on, and need to use the MySql .NET Connector. My boss does not want me to use NuGet for the MySql .NET connector, due to concerns with not being able to verify the file checksums. I was able to download it from the MySql website and verify the checksums. I can't figure out how to reference it in my project so I can use it in my code. Can anyone help me figure this out? I am using VS Code

Comment: "I was able to download the windows version of the connector and verify the checksums" as in the DLL file that nuget would have done for you? Yes, that's the manual way to install a third party library.

Comment: And nuget can do content hashing if you enable [lock files](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/enable-repeatable-package-restores-using-a-lock-file/)

Comment: Thank you for the info on lock files I will dig into this and talk to my boss. I'm newer to working in .NET and we have some pretty strict rules about what we can use. I installed the connector, but can't seem to use it in the project I'm working on. What do I need to do to add a reference to it in the project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a reference to the MySQL connector for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102281/how-do-i-add-a-reference-to-the-mysql-connector-for-net)

Comment: Unfortunately those instructions seem to be for Visual Studio not VS Code. I don't think there is an option in vs code to add reference by right clicking.

Comment: Tell your boss: if he wants results, he needs to stop being cheap and buy you VS and secondly the 80s called: they want their dll hell back. *smh

Comment: any chance you will be able to use 3rd party tools like https://www.sqlshack.com/visual-studio-code-for-mysql-and-mariadb-development/